# How to run concurrent tasks via pool of child processes sharing readonly data (readonly memory sharing) spawned from IPython Notebook on Windows 10

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook, shared-memory

The motivating problem is the following: I want to find the best values for the parameters of a recommendation algorithm by running multiple offline experiments with different parameter value assignments. Each experiment is basically a simulation of transactions through time and the algorithm makes recommendations along the way and some performance metrics are computed at the end. Aside from the parameters, all experiments depend on pretty much the same readonly data, namely: 1) a database of transactions, i.e. a sorted list of Purchase Events (where Purchase Event is a Class that contains data such as timestamp, IDs of items purchased, ID of customer, etc.), 2) several large numpy feature matrices with dimensions N x F (N = number of items, F = number of features), and possibly 3) some dictionaries mapping item IDs to additional metadata.

In order to speed up the parameters search, it would be ideal to run multiple experiments concurrently by taking advantage of all the machine's available cores. However, the shared readonly data should be loaded onto memory only once, as loading a copy of the same data for each experiment would be unfeasible (the loading process can be very time-consuming and all the duplicates together would not fit into RAM).

Does anybody know how something like this could be accomplished? In my opinion this sounds as a perfect job for multithreading, but it turns out that multithreading in Python does not support concurrent execution of CPU-bound tasks because of the GIL. Therefore I assume multiprocessing should be the way to go instead, but then I'm faced with this problem of sharing a lot of complex readonly data (list of class objects, numpy arrays, dictionaries, etc.), which I'm not sure of how to go about implementing.

Moreover, I already have a relatively large codebase implemented on Python 3.5.2 provided by Anaconda, with many Jupyter Notebooks, which work perfectly ok on Windows 10 but unfortunately only allows me to perform experiments in a sequential manner, which is the part I precisely want to refactor to make it work concurrently. I would appreciate for any proposed solution to keep this constraint in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. To use it you have to pack your algorithm in one big function. So you start your program, read your data, and run many instances of your function using `Pool.map`.